# Single list to df multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

How to create df with 4 columns with single list like this:

```
['Dave',  '2008-09-20',  '2020-05-31',  'dave@google.com',  'Steve',  '2009-01-23',  '2020-04-30',  'steve@gmail.com',  'Rob', '2007-02-14',  '2020-04-30',  'rob@gmail.com',  'Ryan',  '2010-02-11', '2020-03-10',  'ryan@yahoo.com']
```

i use this code but it doesnt work out:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.Series(data[0].splitlines()).str.split(',',expand=True).T.set_index(0).T.dropna()
df
```

Comment: Whats data contains?

Answer (score 4):

You can use numpy to reshape the array before loading it:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(-1, 4))

       0           1           2                3
0   Dave  2008-09-20  2020-05-31  dave@google.com
1  Steve  2009-01-23  2020-04-30  steve@gmail.com
2    Rob  2007-02-14  2020-04-30    rob@gmail.com
3   Ryan  2010-02-11  2020-03-10   ryan@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
lst = ['Dave',  '2008-09-20',  '2020-05-31',  'dave@google.com',  'Steve',  '2009-01-23',  '2020-04-30',  'steve@gmail.com',  'Rob', '2007-02-14',  '2020-04-30',  'rob@gmail.com',  'Ryan',  '2010-02-11', '2020-03-10',  'ryan@yahoo.com']
df = pd.DataFrame([lst[i:i+4] for i in range(0,len(lst),4)])
print(df)
```

Output

```
     0           1          2           3
0   Dave    2008-09-20  2020-05-31  dave@google.com
1   Steve   2009-01-23  2020-04-30  steve@gmail.com
2   Rob     2007-02-14  2020-04-30  rob@gmail.com
3   Ryan    2010-02-11  2020-03-10  ryan@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend just use the most basic way to do things.

```
import pandas as pd
arr = ['Dave',  '2008-09-20',  '2020-05-31',  'dave@google.com',  'Steve',  '2009-01-23',  '2020-04-30',  'steve@gmail.com',  'Rob', '2007-02-14',  '2020-04-30',  'rob@gmail.com',  'Ryan',  '2010-02-11', '2020-03-10',  'ryan@yahoo.com']
mat = []
for x in range(0,len(arr),4):
    mat.append(arr[x:x+4])
print(pd.DataFrame(mat))
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth coming up with column names and giving each person an ID before you create the dataframe. The good news is that once that's done, you don't need any loops here, making the conversion efficient. The pivot function will give each person their own row.

```
import pandas as pd
lst =['Dave',  '2008-09-20',  '2020-05-31',   'dave@google.com',  'Steve',  '2009-01-23',  '2020-04-30',  'steve@gmail.com',  'Rob', '2007-02-14',  '2020-04-30',  'rob@gmail.com',  'Ryan',  '2010-02-11', '2020-03-10',  'ryan@yahoo.com']

row_num = len(lst)//4
cols = ['name','start_date','end_date','email']*row_num
ids = sorted([1,2,3,4]*row_num)

df = pd.DataFrame([ids,cols,lst]).T.pivot(index=0,columns=1)[2]
```